# How do I calculate the average from an array of conditional medians using a single formula?

Tags: excel, dynamic-arrays

I need to perform a 2-Step calculation in one formula.

The dataset contains several entries for each article and looks like that:

[image]

As of now, I use a "helper"-column to obtain an array of conditional Medians first and calculate the average afterwards.

Step 1: Calculate the Median %-Price Change per product.

[image]

Step 2: Calculate the average from these Medians (counting each article once).

[image]

I would like to combine these two steps in one formula (i.e. by making use of dynamic array functions).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Excel have you got? Dynamic arrays hints towards Excel O365?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking maybe a helper column is easier. However, it can be done in O365 which my employer has kindly provided:

```
=AVERAGE((INDEX(SORTBY(B:B,A:A,1,B:B,1),MATCH(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")),A:A,0)+FLOOR((COUNTIF(A:A,UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")))-1)/2,1))+
INDEX(SORTBY(B:B,A:A,1,B:B,1),MATCH(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")),A:A,0)+CEILING((COUNTIF(A:A,UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")))-1)/2,1)))/2)
```

So basically the match gives you an array of the row numbers where each group starts, and the floor/ceiling functions give you an offset from there to the mid-point of the sorted numbers within that group.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) for description of 'case-free' form of the median function.

Assumes that the data is pre-sorted on the group letter, but not on the numbers within each group.

[image]

So Index now gives you an array without a hack - I didn't know that before attempting this.

Comment: Not yet sure why, but it works perfectly. Thank you for the sophisticated solution Tom!